# Matlab/simulink error in compilation

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am getting this error in the Simulink file. I have basically connected 3 constants to a MATLAB function which calculates 2 outputs but not able to get why I'm getting the error. The error message reads:

```
"Making simulation target "untitled14_sfun", ... 
'untitled14_sfun.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
operable program or batch file."
```

Comment: Care to share the contents of that MATLAB function?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you haven't installed a compiler (see [here](http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2013b/index.html) for a list of supported compilers), or you have not set it up correctly by running

```
>> mex -setup
```

at the MATLAB command prompt.